# What we use SIGN function in a fortran code?

Tags: fortran, sign

Can someone explain benefit of the using sign function in a fortran code. Why do we need? Rather than its definition I will appreciate in an example.

Comment: Scroll down for the examples.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIGN.html

Comment: I have to admit I don't think I've ever used SIGN in code in the 30+ years I've been writing Fortran. And I'm mildly curious myself as to why it is there. A complete guess - maybe it could vectorise on ancient Crays as opposed to IFs or similar, and so it's there for performance reasons

Comment: Wherever you need the mathematical sign function. There are many uses. In slope/flux limiters https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/src/limiters.f90 Or when you need to store an integer whether a vector does or does not have a non-zero component in some direction, there will be many more. Voting to close as too broad.